# spring boot running as init.d Service (System V) - customize umask for logs

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, redhat

Our Spring Boot aplicattion is deployed as a service, according to this instruction from Spring Boot manual:
[2.2.1. Installation as an init.d Service (System V)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html#deployment.installing.nix-services.init-d)

Our operating system is RedHat Linux 8

---

The service is executed as another user `appuser` specified in the `RUN_AS_USER` environment variable.
The problem we have is that the permissions of logs files generated by the application are wrongly set to `rw-----` but only when the service is started by `root` user (using `service our-service start` command). 
When the service is started by `appuser` user, the permissions of logs are properly set to `rw-r--r--`.

---

The question is: how can we change the permissions of logs when the service is started by `root` ?